# UICollectionViewFlowLayout cell size never changes despite sizeForItemAt implemented

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that has a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` inside. I am making the cell the delegate and the datasource of the collection view. I am conforming to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implementing `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` (and returning the correct size).

However, when I call `layout.itemSize.height` I get the default height, 50.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  fileprivate lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(SomeOtherCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SomeOtherCell.reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return collectionView
  }()

  fileprivate lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? = {
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout?.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    return layout
  }()

  override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
  collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: layoutMargins.left, y: origin.y, width: width, height: layout.itemSize.height)
  // layout.itemSize.height is always 50
  }
}
extension MyCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    guard tags.count != 0 else {
        return .zero
    }

    let tag = Tag(text: tags[indexPath.item], index: indexPath.item)
    placeholderCell.configure(with: tag)
    let size = placeholderCell.getFrame(at: .zero, fitting: placeholderCell.width, alignedBy: semanticContentAttribute, apply: false).size
    collectionViewWidth += size.width
  // this size is always correct, that's what I want when I call  layout.itemSize.height 
    return size
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Problem

- According to [Apple documents for UICollectionViewFlowLayout's itemSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617711-itemsize)

  > If the delegate does not implement the collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) method, the flow layout uses the value in this property to set the size of each cell. This results in cells that all have the same size.
  >
  > The default size value is (50.0, 50.0).
- It says clearly that `itemSize` is only used when the delegate does not implement the collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) method and **no words mention that `itemSize` will return value from `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`.** They are 2 different values. That's why `itemSize` won't change despite `sizeForItemAt` is implemented

  So it makes sense if `layout.itemSize.height` has default value (50) when you use it.

## What is the solution for your problem?

- If all of cells on your `collectionView` have same size, I suggest to set a value for `itemSize` and don't implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` method (Remove extension for `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`).

  ```
  class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    fileprivate lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
      let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
      // collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
      collectionView.register(SomeOtherCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SomeOtherCell.reuseIdentifier)
      collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
      collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
      return collectionView
    }()

    fileprivate lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? = {
      let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
      layout?.scrollDirection = .horizontal
      layout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
      // Calculate and change |itemSize| here
      layout?.itemSize = YOUR_CELL_SIZE_AFTER_CALCULATED
      return layout
    }()

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
      collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: layoutMargins.left, y: origin.y, width: width, height: layout.itemSize.height)
      // layout.itemSize.height is |YOUR_CELL_SIZE_AFTER_CALCULATED.height|
    }
  }
  ```
- If `collectionView` has different size for each cell, you need to use [UICollectionView's layoutAttributesForItem(at:) method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618093-layoutattributesforitem). Get UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes at an IndexPath and use layoutAttributes.size to calculate

  layoutAttributes.size is value returned from `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`

  ```
  let indexPath = // IndexPath you need to use to calculate
  let layoutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
  //  Use this value to calculate |collectionView| frame
  print(layoutAttributes?.size)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem with register ... remove it and set the cell in storyboard. Just a wild guess...

You have 2 cells which one is registered for the collectionView?

In case you set the cell in storyboard, register might also cause a problem

```
  collectionView.register(SomeOtherCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SomeOtherCell.reuseIdentifier)
```